# How to make default svg origin of a group at bottom left instead of top right

Tags: html, css, svg

Say I have a svg group which I  translated the position  like so :

```
<g transform="translate(150,30)">
    <rect x="0" y="10" width="10" height="100"/>
</g>
```

Now this assumes the origin is top left of the rectangle group and the new position is where the top left point of the rectangle  is 150 ,30

[image]

How can I translate a group  on it's bottom left position instead ,for instance the same translate should give me

[image]

Comment: Have you tried minus?

Comment: transform="scale(0, -1) translate(...)", adjust/set the translate as nesessary. Beware that any text you put in that group will display upside down though.